# getting contract address on remix compiler

Tags: remix

When a contract is deployed on remix online web compiler, it displays the deployment by  showing:

browser/thecontract.sol:TheContract at 0xb9b...3de18 (blockchain)

How can we copy/paste the full contract address on remix ?  It is only showing
a part of it  0xb9b...3de18.

Remix is providing copy buttons for account addresses, but i cannot see any copy button for deployed contracts.

Comment: Have you clicked the `Create` button? (Just compiling the contract doesn't deploy it.) You should see the same copy button once you've created an instance of the contract.

Answer (score 3):

On `Remix` app `version 0.8.0`, you should:

1. Click on `DEPLOY` icon, left ribbon;
2. List `TRANSACTIONS` (check deployed contracts);
3. Copy to clipboard.

[image: Remix IDE]

Answer (score 2):

On the upper right there is an icon , just next to the *0xb9b...3de18 you are mentionning .

Just click it and you will have the complete address in your clipboard .

(Of course this will only appear if you correctly deployed your contract.)

Comment: thanks a lot, after making the right subwindow wider, i have seen it.